# How to update a title block in OrCad?

Tags: orcad

I've created a custom title block for my schematics. The problem is that I've already started the project and it is in advanced state of progress. How can I update it? Is it even possible?

Comment: Is it editable i.e. is it a symbol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t need to delete-and-replace the title blocks. They are in the Design Cache like every other library element placed in the OrCAD schematic.

Add the library that contains your title block, select the title block being used in Design Cache, then do ‘replace cache’, sourcing your new block from library. Your new block will appear on all the pages.